# Visual Studio 2019 new solution location

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

I want to create a new .NET Core Console App and have an option to choose a location.

Currently Visual Studio 2019 is putting every console app in the same location and doesn't let me change the location or the name...

Just to be clear, I open Visual Studio 2019 and see this:

[image]

I click Create a new Project

[image]

Select Console App (.NET Core), click Create

A new project is created in `L:\ExhaustivePatternMatching` and it's always called ConsoleApp1, but if I create another it goes into same folder and is called ConsoleApp2...

Is their a setting I can change so that I can select the project / solution location and also the name?

Edit: I upgraded to version and it sorta works...

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I am running preview 3 and after clicking 'Create' in the 'Create new project' page, I get a dialog  to change name & location of the project/solution...

Comment: Didn't realise I'm not on latest, I'm only on PReview 2.0. I'll update and see if it fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to Version 3.0 and it sorta works, albeit with a messed up interface

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Resharper messes things up on that dialog, sometime freezes it, and may also completely wipe out the location input fields.  Refresh / reinstall the newest Resharper to fix it.